# QueryDSL - How to use a StringPath in a where

Tags: querydsl

I have creted a dynamic query from a string column like this:

```
String myColumn = "name";
String myName = "John";

QStudent student = QStudent.student;
query.from(student);

StringPath column = Expressions.stringPath(student, myColumn);

query.where(column.eq(myName));
```

That works just fine! How ever I also need this same code to work when the field is not a String, like this:

```
String myColumn = "some_id";
Long myId = "10";

QStudent student = QStudent.student;
query.from(student);

StringPath column = Expressions.stringPath(student, myColumn);

query.where(column.eq(myId));
```

I get an error right on **column.eq(myId)** because myId is not a String.

My question is regarding how can I do this comparison without changing the type of myId to String?

The error msg:

*The method eq(String) in the type SimpleExpression is not applicable for the arguments*

Answer (score 2):

A general pattern for your case would be

```
query.where(Expressions.path(myId.getClass(), student, myColumn).eq(myId));
```

alternatively for numbers

```
query.where(Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, student, myColumn).eq(myId));
```

By where does `QStudent` come from?